# Use the product rule, find the derivative $(x+6x^{1/2})(x-2x^{1/2}+1)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f(x)=(x+6 \sqrt x) (x-2 \sqrt x+1)$

$f'(x)=[1+3x^{-1/2}](x-2x^{1/2}+1)+(x+6x^{1/2})[1-1x^{-1/2}]
=x-2x^{1/2}+1+3x^{1/2}-6x+3x^{-1/2}+x-1x^{1/2}+6x^{1/2}-6x
    =6x^{1/2}+3x^{-1/2}-9$

can someone check my answer? I think I did something wrong.

Comment: this is your 5th question on derivatives, why don't you use $LaTeX$ formatting?

Comment: Oh, I thought this was a place to ask math questions. Sorry.

Comment: It is, but you should know that derivative questions and a lot of other stuff, can be done by wolfram alpha easily. Also, without going to deeply on your question it seems you just want someone to check your question...not very interesting maths, it could be considered just arithmetic...

Comment: @envy: I didn't say anything implying this is no place to ask mathematics questions, this place has its own rules and one of them is to use $LaTeX$ formatting.

Comment: I edited your latex formula to make it more understandable. Take some time and review what I did. Is not that difficult to learn ;-) And by the way once someone post an answer that for you is ok, please mark it as an answer. Is good courtesy. NOTE: I didn't correct the formulas. Just corrected the latex. So there are some mistakes (parenthesis also...)

Comment: Thanks again. I know what the answer is but I can't seem to get there. I'll get there eventually. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You miss one parenthese in the first step of your derivative; it must be [1 -x^(-1/2)]. Also remember that 1 x is x.

Comment: I expanded my answer. I highlighted your mistakes. Is now clearer? Otherwise just ask.

Answer (score 2):

Wolfram alpha says it is $2x+6\sqrt x+3/\sqrt x-11$. Link is [HERE](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20of%20%28x%2b6%2asqrt%28x%29%29%2a%28x-2%2asqrt%28x%29%2b1%29)

And by the way, since in your expression you have a term $x^2$ you must have a term linear in $x$ in your derivative... Just as a simple check.

So your mistakes were: $x^{1/2} x^{-1/2}=1$ and not $x$. So you have two terms in your equations $-6x$ that should just be $-6$ for a total of $-12$. The rest is ok. If you sum the other terms you get the correct result.

Comment: Thanks, that was the first thing I did.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the product rule correctly, but don't you think
$$x^{1/2}\times x^{-1/2}=x?$$
This is incorrect.

The following is correct.
$$x^{1/2}\times x^{-1/2}=x^{(1/2)-(1/2)}=x^0=1.$$

I think this is the main problem.